# How to get specific realm from Multiple realms for authorization in Shiro?

Tags: java, spring, shiro

I am newbie to Spring and Shiro platforms.

I have two url sets `/admin/--` and `/vendor/--`. Both client sets are authenticating with specific realms. I have extended `ModularRealmAuthenticator` class to choose correct realm for authenticating.

ModularRealmAuthenticator.java

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doAuthenticate(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
    assertRealmsConfigured();
    MultiLoginAuthenticationToken mlat = null;
    Realm loginRealm = null;

    if (!(authenticationToken instanceof MultiLoginAuthenticationToken)) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Unrecognized token , not a typeof MultiLoginAuthenticationToken ");
    } else {
        mlat = (MultiLoginAuthenticationToken) authenticationToken;
        logger.debug("realm name is : {}", mlat.getRealmName());
        loginRealm = lookupRealm(mlat.getRealmName());
    }

    return doSingleRealmAuthentication(loginRealm, mlat);

}

protected Realm lookupRealm(String realmName) throws AuthenticationException {
    Collection<Realm> realms = getRealms();
    for (Realm realm : realms) {
        if (realm.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(realmName)) {
            logger.debug("look up realm name is : {}", realm.getName());
            return realm;
        }
    }
    throw new AuthenticationException("No realm configured for Client " + realmName);
}
```

But while I am assigning role and permissions from different set of datasource to both clients (Admin and vendor). It is iterating the realms in order which I have defined in applicationContext.xml file.

My ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">

    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="com.yatra.mp.security.MultiLoginAuthenticator"/>
    </property>

    <!-- Single realm app (realm configured next, below). If you have multiple 
        realms, use the 'realms' property instead. -->
    <property name="realms">
        <util:list>
            <ref bean="adminAuthRealm" />
            <ref bean="vendorAuthRealm" />              
        </util:list>
    </property>

    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
</bean>
```

In both of realms are extending **AuthorizingRealm** class and both have **doGetAuthorizationInfo** and **doGetAuthenticationInfo** method. In which I have defined my custom implementation.

Is it necessary to extend **ModularRealmAuthorizer** class? If yes, could you please tell me which method I have override?

Comment: It is unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: Hi Wouter, My ques is: I have two type of users(Admin and vendors) in my application. Both type of users are using two table for authentication and both are having different permissions which is authorize with different table from same database. I am using two realms for authentication and authorization for two types of users which are extending AuthorizingRealm class. I wrote above custom Authenticator which is calling correct Realm for authentication. but while doing Authorization, it is calling wrong realm

Comment: (i.e. realm is executing for authorizing in order in which we have defined in applicationContext.xml file). So My question is How to get call correct Realm for authorization for paticular user? Because Both Realms are having doGetAuthenticationInfo  method to assign the roles and permissions to particular type of users. Please let me know if you have any other question on this. I am stuck in this issue from couple of days. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add the domain info to the PrincipalCollection you can wrap in the AuthenticationInfo. It is an added token in the principal collection that gets carried over in subsequent shiro calls. You can use that info in the authentication to skip if it doesn't match your realm. This is actually what we do in our custom realm:

```
public class OurRealmImpl extends AuthorizingRealm

...
    @Override
    public AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) {
        ... //check if user exists and read passwordhash
        Login ourLoginToken = ...
        SimplePrincipalCollection principalCollection = new SimplePrincipalCollection(ourLoginToken, realmName);
        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(principalCollection, passwordHash);
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        Collection collection = principals.fromRealm(realmName);
        if (collection.isEmpty()) {
           return null;
        }
        Login login = (Login) collection.iterator().next();
        ... get the rights and return authorization
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        info.addStringPermissions(permissionStrings);
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, Thanks a million. I have Override the "supports" method in both realms. That's why I am able to call correct Realm for Authentication. But I am not getting the reason why it is not being called for Authorization.. Could you please let me know the reason?

Comment: I have added below code in both realms:
`code
@Override
    public boolean supports(AuthenticationToken token) {
  if (token instanceof MultiLoginAuthenticationToken) {
            return ((MultiLoginAuthenticationToken)token).getRealmName().equalsIgnoreCase("AdminAuthRealm");
        }
        return false;
    }
`

Comment: Hi Wouter, I have read the Shiro articles. As per I understood the concept, supports method called only for authentication, not for Authorization. And in my case, Authentication is working fine. I am facing problem in Authorization process. Please let me know what can I do with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Totally misunderstood the question. I have changed the answer to I hope you were asking. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 0):

i met that problem too. finally, i solved it. step as the follow:

**1) let a new class to extend the ModularRealmAuthorizer.**

```
public class OurModularRealmAuthorizer extend ModularRealmAuthorizer{
  private map<string,OurAuthorizerRealm> mRealms;
  private map<string,OurAuthorizerRealm> getMRealms(){return mRealms;}
  private void setMRealms(map<string,OurAuthorizerRealm> mrealms){
      this.mRealms = mrealms;
      Collection<Realm> tmpRealms = new ArrayList<Realm>();

        for (OurAuthorizerRealm value : mrealms.values()) {
            Realm realm = (Realm) value;
            tmpRealms.add(realm);
        }

        this.realms = tmpRealms;/*setting realms*/
  }
}
```

**2. spring-shiro.xml:**

```
<bean id="ourModularRealmAuthorizer" class="xx.xxx.shiro.realm.ShiroModularRealmAuthorizer">
        <property name="mRealms">
            <map>
                <entry key="ourAuthorizerRealm1" value-ref="ourAuthorizerRealm1" />
                <entry key="ourAuthorizerRealm2" value-ref="ourAuthorizerRealm2" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="authenticator" ref="ourModularRealmAuthenticator"></property>
        <property name="authorizer" ref="ouModularRealmAuthorizer"></property>
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="shiroCacheManager"></property>
    </bean>
```

all right.